# Inheritance with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance

So I have a class Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :category_id, :name
end
```

and a class UserCategory.

```
class UserCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :category_id, usercategory_id

  self.table_name = 'contractor_categories'
  self.primary_key = :nid
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id",
             :inverse_of => :categories
end
```

So when I do `User.last.categories.first.name`
I would like to get the name of the first associated category.

How should I do that without doing something like: `Category.find(User.last.categories.first.category_id).name`

Edit: I'm currently doing:

```
def name
    Category.find(self.category_id).name
  end
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Is the `Category` model associated with `UserCategory` or `User` in any way? No relationship is shown in your code example.

Comment: @mbratch Nope, Category doesn't have any association yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your model you can add an association

```
belongs_to :category
```

and then your `name` method would look like this

```
def name
  category.name
end
```

or you could do `User.last.categories.first.category.name` which would save you creating a name method, but I'm not sure why you would prefer that.

Comment: Better yet, perform the first step then, instead of defining the `name` method, do: `delegate :name, :to => :category`. For more on `delegate` see http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate.

Comment: Doydle. Yep, your solution is very close to what I have 
@kardeiz, Thanks! This is kind of what I was looking for!
 EDit: Damn I can mention only one person per comment, that sucks

Comment: sorry not really an answer but check out Single Table Inheritance

Comment: @bl0b, only one person per comment, but the author of the Answer you comment on gets your comment for free. So you don't have to tag them explicitly. :)